# Azure easiest way to publish and query a list of values

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-rest-api

I am looking for the easiest and cheapest way to use Azure to publish a list of values to be query by my application. I am currently using Azure Application Insights to send telemetry events and try to use a similar mechanisms to serve my need.
I tried to use the Azure Application Insight [query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/query/get) and the tags but I can not find a good way to store the list of values.

I am wondering if a rest API would be the right way forward or if there is something even easier? The system is very similar to a revocation list:

1. The list is published with no security (e.g. simply use the API key)
2. The C# client starts and retrieves the list and perform some action is the list is successfully retrieved.

Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: Just guessing: I suppose your list might be in JSON format? You could just put a JSON file on blob or CDN storage and grab it anonymously. Even if it's CSV or text or whatever, this approach works fine

Comment: Thanks Nick, I have not decided the the format but it is a pair of value (label:Id). A CDN on my existing storage account might be a good option. I'll give it a try and let you know shortly.

Comment: The CDN might be interesting but comes with a running cost. Would you think that the file sharing or table component of the blob storage would be suitable?

Comment: @Salim If you persist to use azure, I think azure table storage would be the choice. Like you can store the key and value into 2 different columns, then query the value by using the key.

Comment: To make a choice, it probably matters how you want to update this list. Is is just a manually updated text file or do you need an API that will let you add and update keys?

Comment: Thanks Ivan and Nick for your input. Regarding update, I will do it manually as there are only a very few update (1x/month). 50k clients will however fetch the list daily. I need to fetch the entire list in one short. Is is possible with the table approach?

Comment: @Salim yes, you can fetch the entire list in one short if you write the property query in azure table storage. See the answer below and let me know if have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application insights` is not a good place to store this kind of data. It will add many extra columns and the query results is not very friendly which may take you lots of time to parse it.

For `azure table storage`, you can store `the key and value pair` into 2 different columns like mykeyColumn / myvalueColumn, then you can easy use the [table storage sdk](http://Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table)(it's available for both `azure table storage` and `azure cosmos db` services) to query the records(one or many) in just one query command.

For better performance, I recommend you can store these key-value pairs with the same `partition key`, then in your code, you can define your query filter like below:

```
TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "xxx")
```

This filter will return all the key-value pairs in the specified `partition key`, next, you can easy to get each of them.

For the usage of the sdk [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table), please refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet#install-the-required-nuget-package).

For the usage of `query filter`, you may take a look at [this doc](https://vkinfotek.com/azureqa/how-do-i-query-azure-table-storage-using-tablequery-class.html)(It may use the old sdk, but the query filter is the same).

And if the key-value pairs will not be updated or no new ones will be added, you can also consider store them in json format, and use the blob storage.

Comment: This is an excellent detailed answer, but if there is no requirement to search/access update individual key values through an API, this is probably overkill. It seems like a flat file stored in blob would satisfy this just as well.

Comment: If it's json format and not updated, blob storage is ok. But table storage is also good when new data is added.